# React: How to load an image by path that contains special characters?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, electron

I have tried to load an image by path that contains special characters like &@^.

When I loaded the image as below, it didn't work.

```
<img src="file:///test/@#$%/0.png"/>
```

So, I've tried to use encodeURI(path), encodeURIComponent(path), but it didn't work too.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to encode each level in your path (skip the `/` characters):

```js
const path = 'file:///test/@#$%/0.png'
const encodedPath = 'file://' + path.replace('file://', '').split('/').map((p) => encodeURIComponent(p)).join('/')
console.log(encodedPath)
// Output: file:///test/%40%23%24%25/0.png
```

Use the above output for your `img` tag, it will be loaded.

Comment: There is one thing to know. In Windows, a path starts with drive letters like C:\, D:\. Because of this, you need to skip encoding ":\" that follows drive letters.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot render them as string. If you want to use them, you must write on Numeric code or JS escape.

You can find their codes from [here](https://www.rapidtables.com/web/html/html-codes.html)

As your wanted,

```
@ : &#64;
# : &#35;
$ : &#36;
```